# Printing newline in `Export` properly

Tags: export

I am using the following code to print some data to an external file :

```
file = OpenAppend["abc.dat"]

Do[Export[file, {u, ClassicalFish[1, 2, 10^-5, 100, u, 2, 40]}]; 
 WriteString[file, "\n"], {u, 0.0003, 0.99, 0.0001}]

Close[file]
```

This writes the data to the file but there is a new line after each `u` and each `ClassicalFish[1, 2, 10^-5, 100, u, 2, 40]}]` in `abc.dat`. If I don't include `WriteString[file, "\n"]` then everything is printed one after the other.

Please provide some solution for this. I would like to print a `"\t"` between each `u` and `ClassicalFish[1, 2, 10^-5, 100, u, 2, 40]}]` pair and after that a `"\n"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid procedural loops in Matehmatica (`Do`, `For`, `While` etc). Instead, generate your dataset with `Table`, then export it all in one go:

```
yourData = Table[
              {u, ClassicalFish[1, 2, 10^-5, 100, u, 2, 40]}, 
              {u, 0.0003, 0.99, 0.0001}
           ];

Export["abc.dat", yourData, "TSV"]
```

Using the `"TSV"` export format will give you tab-separated values, one pair of values per line.

---

Alternative method that exports each result as they are being created:

```
file = OpenAppend["abc.dat"];
Table[
  Export[file, {{u, ClassicalFish[1, 2, 10^-5, 100, u, 2, 40]}}, "TSV"],
  {u, 0.0003, 0.99, 0.1}
]
Close[file]
```

Comment: Actually, I want to print data to file for each run because my code can take even upto 40 hours or so and there is a possibility that I may have to stop the code before full evaluation.

Comment: @Nitin Got it. See the alternative method I added.

Comment: This almost did it, except that there is no `newline` after `ClassicalFish[1, 2, 10^-5, 100, u, 2, 40]` is printed.

Comment: The following does it `Table[Export[
  file, {{u, ClassicalFish[1, 2, 10^-5, 100, u, 2, 40], "\n"}}, 
  "TSV"], {u, 0.0003, 0.99, 0.0001}]` . If you can add this or something similar then I can happily accept this as an answer (since the question is specifically about `newline`). If possible can you also explain why this works? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Nitin, just to clarify, you want TWO new lines after each data entry? i.e. you want an empty line in between each entry? Of course I do not have the definition of `ClassicalFish`, so I do not know what it returns exactly, but if I replace it with any other numerical function (e.g. `Sin[u]`), then each entry is already separated into its own line. Is it different on your system?

Comment: Yes actually it's different on my system. For some reason there is no new line unless I add the `"\n"` part